# "viewFullscreen" menu item is not showing in the context menu of highcharts 6.2.0

Tags: highcharts, angular7

I have a highchart line chart which currently displayed in bootstrap 4 card.
I want it to displayed full screen, which I'm currently aware that highchart 6.2.0 has option to enabled exporting file, so that I can use the exporting context menu. so, I enabled them but "showFullscreen" option not showing in the exporting context menu.

I imported highchart and exporting module to the component.
in the documentation highchart guys says that I have to include viewFullscreen as string to the menuItems array. I also did that. but nothing work.

```
import { chart } from 'highcharts';
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts/highcharts';
import * as HighchartsMore from 'highcharts/highcharts-more';
import * as HighchartsSolidGauge from 'highcharts/modules/solid-gauge';
import * as HighChartExport from 'highcharts/modules/exporting';


HighchartsMore(Highcharts);
HighchartsSolidGauge(Highcharts);
HighChartExport(Highcharts);


@Component({
  selector: 'app-line-chart',
  templateUrl: './line-chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./line-chart.component.css']
})
export class LineChartComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  @ViewChild('chartTarget') chartTarget: ElementRef;
  @Input() data;
  @Input() lineColor;
  options: any;
  chart: Highcharts.ChartObject;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.drawLineChart();
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (this.chart && changes['data']) {
      this.drawLineChart();
    }
  }

  drawLineChart() {
    this.options = {
      chart: {
        scrollablePlotArea: {
          minWidth: 700
        },
        height: 230,
        zoomType: 'x'
      },
      title: {
        text: ''
      },
      credits: {
        enabled: false
      },
      xAxis: {
        gridLineWidth: 1,
        /*tickInterval: 7 * 24 * 3600 * 1000, // one week
        tickWidth: 0,*/
        labels: {
          align: 'left',
          x: 3,
          y: -3,
          enabled: false
        }
      },
      yAxis: [{ // left y axis
        title: {
          text: null
        },
        padding: 3,
        showFirstLabel: false,
        gridLineWidth: 1,
        /*labels: {
          align: 'left',
          x: -10
        }*/
      }],
      colors: this.lineColor,
      legend: {
        align: 'left',
        verticalAlign: 'bottom',
        borderWidth: 0
      },
      tooltip: {
        shared: true,
        crosshairs: true,
        headerFormat: ''
      },
      exporting: {
        enabled: true,
        menuItemDefinitions: {
          // Custom definition
        },
        buttons: {
          contextButton: {
            menuItems: ['viewFullscreen']
          }
        }
      },
      plotOptions: {
        series: {
          cursor: 'pointer',
          marker: {
            enabled: false
          }
        }
      },
      series: this.data
    };
    this.chart = chart(this.chartTarget.nativeElement, this.options as any);
  }

}
```

I followed this link https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/exporting/menuitemdefinitions/

but when I clicked that hamburger icon every other options showing except "viewFullscreen" option didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

To add a custom button to context menu you have to add it to `exporting.menuItemDefinitions` and also `exporting.buttons.contextButton.menuItems` array. Note, that fullscreen requires an additional module to be loaded: **modules/full-screen**.

**Code:**

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  exporting: {
    menuItemDefinitions: {
      fullscreen: {
        onclick: function() {
          Highcharts.FullScreen.prototype.init(this.renderTo);
        },
        text: 'Full screen'
      }
    },
    buttons: {
      contextButton: {
        menuItems: ['downloadPNG', 'downloadSVG', 'separator', 'fullscreen']
      }
    }
  },
  series: [{
    data: [
      43934,
      52503,
      57177,
      69658,
      97031,
      119931,
      137133,
      154175
    ]
  }],
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/full-screen.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qydgxs12/

**Angular demo:**

- https://codesandbox.io/s/73lomvnqk0

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.buttons.contextButton.menuItems
- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.menuItemDefinitions

Comment: hi, I'm installed highcharts using npm and in my node folder , highcharts/modules folder there is not full-screen module.

Comment: Hi @Nadee, are you sure you've installed Highcharts version 7 or newer? Note, that this module is not available in previous versions.

Comment: actually this is my question in the topic, I want to know is there any option available in Highchart 6.2.0 version.

Comment: Oh, sorry I somehow missed it. Of course, you can load this module manually and use it with version 6.2.0. Check this example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qpxfjg, api: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular#to-load-a-wrapper

Comment: thank you! but full screen option is not working when I clicked it.  stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qpxfjg also same

Comment: Yes, however, it could be a problem with online editors. Try to open the view in new window and try it: https://angular-qpxfjg.stackblitz.io/

Comment: now its opening in the full screen mode but bottom half of the screen is black. only upper half showing the chart. any thoughts ?

Comment: Try it on a local app, perhaps it is only an issue with online editors.