# Highcharts view full screen in older version

Tags: highcharts

I am uisng highcharts version 6.1.0, I see view full screen option is available only in highcharts version 7 0r 7+. Is there a way I can get this full screen view feature in before versions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55532964/viewfullscreen-menu-item-is-not-showing-in-the-context-menu-of-highcharts-6-2

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own context menu button with `onclick` function:

```
exporting: {
    menuItemDefinitions: {
        viewFullscreen: {
            onclick: function() {
                var container = this.renderTo;

                if (container.requestFullscreen) {
                    container.requestFullscreen();
                } else if (container.mozRequestFullScreen) {
                    container.mozRequestFullScreen();
                } else if (container.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
                    container.webkitRequestFullscreen();
                } else if (container.msRequestFullscreen) {
                    container.msRequestFullscreen();
                }
            },
            text: 'View in full screen'
        }
    },
    buttons: {
        contextButton: {
            menuItems: ["viewFullscreen", "printChart", "separator", "downloadPNG", "downloadJPEG", "downloadPDF", "downloadSVG"]
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/oyz836v7/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.menuItemDefinitions